# Custom page template how to check is_page from functions.php?

Tags: functions, page-template, excerpt

Have a custom page template and trying to make the excerpt length dynamical depending on what page you are in.

Functions.php

```
<?php

function custom_excerpt_length($length){
    if (is_page(15)) {
    return 20;
    } else {
    return 150; 
    }
}
add_filter ( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length');

?>
```

cant get is_page to work from functions in my custom template page.

If i try `echo is_page(15);` in the static custom template value is **true**.

i'am little confused. Is it possible to call `is_page()` from *functions.php* (WP 3.1.2)

Comment: Do you see anything if you call `var_dump( is_page( 15 ) )` in your `custom_excerpt_length()` function?

Comment: that is the problem. If i `var_dump(is_page(15));` from functions.php its always bool(false) but if try it from header.php the value is true. Sorry about my English

Comment: If you just put it in `functions.php` (not in a function in that file) it will be executed too early, before WordPress knows it is a page or not. If you do it in the `custom_excerpt_length()` function it should work, because this function is called by `excerpt_length`, and at that moment WordPress should know that it is on a page. - But you say you do this in a special page template - a separate file in your template directory? Then you can also specify it there. (Use `@Jan` when you reply and I get a notification.)

Comment: @Jan when i try `var_dump(is_page(15));` inside the function i get bool(false). The function works but the `is_page(15);` don't work inside the function. I think it is best to put the function without the `is_page();` in the custom template page (it is a separate file in template directory). So the excerpt does not interfere the other pages.

Comment: always be aware that a custom query in the main code of the template can distort the original $query_string; make sure that all queries are restoring the original $query_string. or try to add `wp_reset_query();` before your conditional `is_page(15)`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `is_page()` inside functions.php is fine, possible and working, and if you are echoing `is_page(15)` and getting  true, that means you are on a page with the ID of 15.

the problem could be the priority parameter of the add_filter call, form the codex:

> Make sure to set the priority
>   correctly, else the default WordPress
>   filter on this function will run last
>   and override what you set here.

so change your code to :

```
add_filter ( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length',999);
```

Comment: I see no other filters on `excerpt_length` in the WordPress core, so I think this is an old recommendation. But it is always possible that in this case another piece of code (a plugin?) is hooking into this filter with a higher priority.

Comment: ok. so it should return true if i call echo is_page(15); from functions.php and entering to page id(15). When i try it from header.php it works but not from functions

Comment: it doesn't matter where the code is as long as its included and since its in a function in you functions.php its included. and it works just fine in my functions.php

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information. Have to fix it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution based on `url_to_postid` function

```
$url = explode('?', 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$ID = url_to_postid($url[0]);
```

With this I can get post/page ID within the `functions.php` file.

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing to do with it being in the functions file, but rather that the function is being called within 'The Loop' because it is attached to the excerpt filter. is_page() will always return false inside the loop, so it's not useful there.

Comment: No, it should work. `is_page()` checks the global `$wp_query` which stores the 'main query' and so can be used pretty much anywhere after the query has been set up. In fact 'the Loop' is called from within the template - so although the code might be in `functions.php`, it'll be triggered by the template.