# Can not hook into custom post type template with: is_page() conditional?

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, conditional-tags

I am using a custom post type: FAQ, to create an ongoing page of FAQ items.

I have created a custom template: faq-template.php, to display the items.

I need to hook other elements into the bottom of this page and various other pages. (Genesis framework.)

The problem is that when I use is_page() to conditionally hook the other elements, it fails, but only on the custom page template, with a custom loop.

I have marked up the code in detail to explain the issue.

Here's the template code:

```
//Custom post type loop for FAQ:

function my_custom_loop() {

global $post;

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'faq',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'orderby'       => 'menu_order' 
);

echo get_the_id(); //For testing. This successfully outputs the page ID: #19 at the top of the page template in question, so I know that Wordpress recognizes this page as #19.

global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( have_posts() ) : 

   do_action ('genesis_before_entry_content');

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

    $title=get_the_title();
    $content=get_the_content();

    endwhile;

    echo do_shortcode("[accordion]");

    do_action( 'genesis_after_endwhile' );

    do_action ('genesis_after_entry_content'); //Hooking stuff here

endif;

wp_reset_query();
}

add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'bmg_custom_loop' );
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );

genesis();
```

Here are the conditionals and the content I am hooking, from functions.php:

```
//Hook some buttons into the bottom of certain pages:

add_action( 'genesis_after_entry_content', 'my_page_buttons',999); //Where to hook

function my_page_buttons()
{

 //FIRST put the buttons only on the last page of multi-page items that use <!--nextpage-->
// OR if not multi-page, then put it on singular pages:

global $multipage, $numpages, $page;
if ( $multipage && $page == $numpages || 1 !== $multipage ) { 

//NEXT put it on specific pages that meet the above condition.
//This is the part that fails for page ID #19 only, the FAQ page template.

   if ( is_page( array( //put the buttons on these pages
        //When I delete this conditional, the buttons appear fine on ALL pages, including #19
        19, // Why does the FAQ page does not accept it's page ID #19 with is_page()?
        99,
        98,
        13,
        113,
    ) ) )

    { //Here's the output:
?>

<div class="button-row">
<a class="button" href="<?php echo get_permalink( 49 );?> ">BUTTON ONE</a> 
<a class="button" href="<?php echo get_permalink( 97 );?>">BUTTON TWO</a>
</div> 

<?php  
}
}
}
```

My question again: Why does is_page() fail as a conditional on my custom post type template?

I have looked at several other related topics but didn't find an answer:
[Why is custom template not seen as page with is_page()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69609/why-is-custom-template-not-seen-as-page-with-is-page)
[Conditional tag is_page with a custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142842/conditional-tag-is-page-with-a-custom-post-type)
[Custom page template how to check is_page from functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16927/custom-page-template-how-to-check-is-page-from-functions-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh... While writing up this question it suddenly became clear why it was not working:

I was hooking my buttons inside the loop and since my loop was not a single page item,  get_the_id() would be getting the ID of each post in the loop, not the page that the posts were on.

All I had to do was hook after the loop:

`add_action( 'genesis_after_loop', 'my_page_buttons');`

I'm posting this just in case someone else has a similar issue.